# Publishing ASP.NET Core 7 Web API on Windows Plesk - error: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-7.0

When I publish my ASP.NET Core 7 Web API on the Windows Plesk host, everything works fine, but when I try to connect and run a query to SQL Server database which is on host, I get this error:

> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=5.0.0.0...

[image]

I decided to install `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` package (I don't know how to use it, I only installed it, but I still get the same error), and these are my packages:

[image]

I have two connection strings - one is in my `DbContext`:

[image]

The other one is in my `appSettings.json` (but there was no connection string on my `appSettings.json` by default, I added it manually):

[image]

I don't know which connection string is used on host, but on my local computer 'DBContext ConnectionString' was working, and I even removed "TrustServerCertificate=True" and I changed the "Database=" to "Initial Catalog=" on both connection strings, still same error.

Comment: Please paste the codes you want to mention as code blocks for better readability, not screenshots

Comment: Do you use EF inside your application? Which version ef core you have used?

Comment: Yes, I have used EF Core 7.0.14, You can see my all packages in the second screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, in ASP.NET Core 6, 7 and 8 after publishing there will be a folder named 'runtimes', You're gonna need it with the project files to deploy on IIS or Hosts